# Counting the amount of wordpress posts and echoing it

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created some sort of breadcrumb which tells the user what filters have been applied and how many posts are showing. My issue is that I am trying to grab the variable before it has been declared, this is because the breadcrumb is above the post loop. Here's the relevant code to show you what I mean;

This is the post loop with my $post_counter variable

```
<section id="properties">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php 
                        if($_GET['min_price'] && !empty($_GET['min_price'])){
                            $min_price = $_GET['min_price'];
                        }else{
                            $min_price = 0;
                        }

                        if($_GET['max_price'] && !empty($_GET['max_price'])){
                            $max_price = $_GET['max_price'];
                        }else{
                            $max_price = 10000000;
                        }

                        if($_GET['min_beds'] && !empty($_GET['min_beds'])){
                            $min_beds = $_GET['min_beds'];
                        }else{
                            $min_beds = '1'; 
                        }

                        if($_GET['max_beds'] && !empty($_GET['max_beds'])){
                            $max_beds = $_GET['max_beds'];
                        }else{
                            $max_beds = '6+'; 
                        }

                        if($_GET['location'] && !empty($_GET['location'])){
                            $location = $_GET['location'];
                            $location_val = stripslashes($location);
                        }

                        if($_GET['type'] && !empty($_GET['type'])){
                            $type = $_GET['type'];
                        }else{
                            $type = array("Detached", "Semi-Detached", "Terraced", "End of Terrace", "Apartment", "Bungalow", "Commercial");
                        }

                        if($_GET['flash_type'] && !empty($_GET['flash_type'])){
                            $flash_type = $_GET['flash_type'];
                        }else{
                            $flash_type = array("Ideal First Time Buy", "Ideal Investment", "Under Offer", "Nothing Selected");
                        }

                    $posts = get_posts(array(
                        'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
                        'post_type'         =>  'property',
                        'orderby'           =>  'date',
                        'meta_query'        =>  array(
                            'relation'  => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'property_status',
                                'value'     => 'For Sale'
                            ),

                            array(
                                'key'       => 'property_price',
                                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                'value'     => array($min_price, $max_price),
                                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
                            ),

                            array(
                                'key'       => 'bedrooms',
                                'value'     => array($min_beds, $max_beds),
                                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
                            ),

                            array(
                                'relation'  => 'OR',
                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'street',
                                    'value'     => $location_val,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                                ),

                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'town',
                                    'value'     => $location_val,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                                ),

                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'county',
                                    'value'     => $location_val,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                                ),

                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'postcode',
                                    'value'     => $location_val,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),

                            array(
                                'key'       => 'type_of_property',
                                'value'     => $type,
                                'compare'   => 'IN'
                            ),

                            array(
                                'key'       => 'optional_category',
                                'value'     => $flash_type,
                                'compare'   => 'IN'
                            ),
                        )
                    ));

                    $post_counter = 0;

                    if( $posts ):?> 

                        <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
                            setup_postdata( $post );
                            $post_counter = $post_counter + 1;
                        ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                <div class="shadowwrapper2">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php  
                                        $main_field = get_field('images');
                                        $first_row = $main_field[0];
                                        $img = $first_row['image'];
                                        $img_med = $img['sizes']['medium'];
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="propertywrapper">
                                        <img class="img-fluid gal_imgs" src="<?php echo $img_med ?>" alt="<?php $img['alt']; ?>"/>

                                        <?php $secondary_flash = get_field('optional_category'); ?>

                                        <?php if($secondary_flash == "Ideal First Time Buy"): ?>
                                            <span class="second_flash">Ideal First Time Buy</span>
                                        <?php elseif($secondary_flash == "Ideal Investment"): ?>
                                            <span class="second_flash">Ideal Investment</span>
                                        <?php elseif($secondary_flash == "Under offer"): ?>
                                            <span class="second_flash">Under offer</span>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="cornerflash">
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/imgs/forsale.svg" alt="corner flash">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="propertyinfo">
                                        <div class="row m-0">
                                            <div class="col-6 p-0 mt-2"><?php the_field('type_of_property'); ?></div>
                                            <div class="col-6 p-0 mt-2"><?php the_field('bedrooms'); ?> bedrooms</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="streetpricewrapper">
                                        <p class="streetname">
                                            <?php the_field('street'); ?>, <?php the_field('town'); ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="price">
                                            £<?php the_field('property_price'); ?>
                                        </p>    
                                    </div>                              
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my breadcrumb this section is above the post loop on my page. This is where I am trying to retrieve the $post_counter variable;

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="crumb">
                <p>Now showing <?php echo $post_counter; ?> properties</p>

                <?php 
                    // check if property type has been selected if so loop through them and display them
                    if( $_GET['type'] ){
                        $crumb_type = $_GET['type'];

                        foreach($crumb_type as $val) {
                            echo '<span>'.$val.', </span>';
                        }
                    }

                    // check if min beds / max beds has been select if so display it in the crumb
                    if( $_GET['min_beds'] ){
                        $crumb_minbeds = $_GET['min_beds'];

                        echo '<p>from </p><span>'.$crumb_minbeds.' bedrooms, </span>';
                    }

                    if( $_GET['max_beds']){
                        $crumb_maxbeds = $_GET['max_beds'];

                        echo '<p>up to </p><span>'.$crumb_maxbeds.' bedrooms, </span>';
                    }

                    // check if min price / max price has been select if so display it in the crumb
                    if( $_GET['min_price'] ){
                        $crumb_minprice = $_GET['min_price'];

                        echo '<p>from </p><span>£'.$crumb_minprice.' </span>';
                    }

                    if( $_GET['max_price']){
                        $crumb_maxprice = $_GET['max_price'];

                        echo '<p>up to </p><span>£'.$crumb_maxprice.' </span>';
                    }

                    // check if location is set 
                    if( $_GET['location'] ){
                        $crumb_location = $_GET['location'];

                        echo '<p>properties in </p><span>'.stripslashes($crumb_location).'</span>';
                    }

                    // check if secondary filters are applied, if so display a clickable box
                    if( $_GET['flash_type'] ): ?>
                        <div id="flash_crumbs">
                            <?php 
                            if( in_array('Ideal First Time Buy', $_GET['flash_type']) ): ?>
                                <a href="javascript:;">Ideal First Time Buy <span data-id="first_time" >&times;</span></a>
                            <?php endif; 

                            if( in_array('Ideal Investment', $_GET['flash_type']) ): ?>
                                <a href="javascript:;">Ideal Investment <span data-id="investment" >&times;</span></a>
                            <?php endif; 

                            if( in_array('Under Offer', $_GET['flash_type']) ): ?>
                                <a href="javascript:;">Under Offer <span data-id="under_offer" >&times;</span></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process everything before displaying it. This way you can separate concerns at your code will look better.

Move your `$posts = get_posts(...)` in the `header.php` in the php tag and inside breadcrumb just write:

```
<p>Now showing <?php echo count($posts); ?> properties</p>
```

[PHP Count](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.count.php)

In general, it it way better to process data before displaying it.

Comment: Not all of my pages have the posts. So for the pages that don't would placing this code in the header.php cause those pages to load slower for no reason? could I create another page for the loop then request it instead?

Comment: That's a great idea. Create a file just for this purpose, to get the posts and include it in the header, BUT, make a check before including to see if the page is the one you want like:`if(in_array($pageSlug,['page1','page2'])){ include('myFile.php') }`. Check this post for 'hot to get the page slug': http://extracatchy.net/retrieve-the-slug-of-current-page-wordpress/